# Hide some Payment method for only specific currency

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, payment-methods, currency

I need to hide my some of payment methods (like 'Bank Transfer') if a customer choose a  currency like $

If our default currency is Euro , all of payment methods should show

but I want to hide some payment methods if $ is selected as currency

Answer (score 1):

You could go with a separate storeview and disabling them as a site specific settings under System / Configuration / Payment methods (for the specific storeview).

Or look if there is a module on Magento connect which does this trick. There are a lot of modules out there to limit payment methods.

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses the base currency for checkout, you need multiple websites for each checkout currency and on the website level you change whether it's active.